# MySQL sudden throughput increase

Tags: mysql, logging, munin

What could be the cause of a sudden increase in MySQL throughput (from an average of 1.5M/s to 7.5M/s). The system is running WordPress on a trafficked site (2M monthly pageviews). The throughput is monitored with munin. Is there a way to see in MySQL how much data a query transfers? Thank you!

Comment: Wordpress/Webserver caching functionality being temporarily disabled could be a cause.

Comment: caching is enabled and seems to be working fine. In munin, the number of queries does not seem to have spiked with the throughput, it looks normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in the end. The source was trivial - a code change causing giant result sets.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on a VM, Slice, or other hosted environment?  If so, your host may have moved you to new hardware, or, more likely, other slices on your hardware may have been moved off or closed.

Comment: We are using a dedicated server, so this was not the cause.